# USB devices and WIN XP

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, usb

Yes, i know. XP!!!
But this is a legacy machine with software compatible with XP only.

Anyhow, this machine will not recognize or display, ANY usb device connected to it. Either on "my computer" or device manager or disk management, not even after changing all possible settings to not suspend USB devices.
Is like you never plugged in anything to it.
As far as i know, USB devices where recognized and used normally some time ago (approximately a month or two).

So for test purposes, i took an SSD i had, connected to machine and installed windows 10 (yes i know, shocking, but i do not have XP nor a valid key for them).
Now, with the new OS, all works just fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to motherboard firmware (BIOS/UEFI) settings and disable USB 3.0 (xHCI). Make sure it's in USB 2.0 (EHCI) mode.

It might also be called Legacy mode under a USB option somewhere.

Comment: Thanks Bob, this now, is litterally one of the "seriously???" moments.
That's exactly what it was. Thanks a million, i was about to go mad. :)